# Dynamic Select Dropdown in Filament not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, laravel-filament, filamentphp

i am working on an issue where i can't find any solution in within the Filament community.

I have one Select Field in Filament with the following code:

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('batch_number')
                            ->required()
                            ->searchable()
                            ->options(
                                    DB::table('fault_prodauf_ios')
                                        ->select('nr')
                                        ->distinct()
                                        ->pluck('nr','nr')
                               )
                            ->live(),
```

This code is redering a list of production numbers. Based on this i would like to render a dependend select with the following code:

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('batch_pos')
                            ->options(function (Forms\Get $get){
                                DB::table('fault_prodauf_ios')
                                    ->where('nr','=',$get('batch_number'))
                                    ->select('pos')
                                    ->distinct()
                                    ->pluck('pos','pos');
                        })
                            ->preload(),
```

Within the debugbar i can see that the Select was done successful with the right data, but the Select field is not rendered with data.
If i delete the Forms\Get and make a standard options call with a hardcoded production number like following, i get a rendered select as expected.

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('batch_pos')
                            ->options(DB::table('fault_prodauf_ios')
                                    ->where('nr','=','23010674')
                                    ->select('pos')
                                    ->distinct()
                                    ->pluck('pos','pos');
                        )
                            ->preload(),
```

Sorry but i am really confused and within other resources a similar code is working well.

Thanks for any hint. Armin

Comment: try remove searchable() and see if it work.